# Nested ionic-angular tabs routing with params

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, ionic4, angular-routing

I am trying to understand the concepts of routing in Angular.

I have created an application with API calls as shown below in the flow diagram.

[image]

**Explanation for the flow**

1. The landing page of the app falls to a tabs layout - [main.routing.module.ts]
2. On click to Tabs 2, you are routed to a new page with list of items - [tabs2.routing.module.ts]
3. On click on one of the items which has its own "id", subitems page is opened. *routerlink is being used with params*
4. On click on one of the subitems which has its own "id", subtabs page is opened. *routerlink is being used with params* - subtabs.routing.module.ts

**main.routing.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { TabsPage } from './tabs.page';
import { AuthGuard } from 'src/app/gaurds/auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'tabs',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        component: TabsPage,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'tabs1',
                canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        loadChildren: () =>
                            import('../tabs1/tabs1.module').then(m => m.Tabs1PageModule)

                    }

                ]
            },
            {
                path: '',
                canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                loadChildren: '../Tabs2/tabs2.routing.module#Tabs2RoutingModule'
            },
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '/tabs/tabs1',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            }
        ]

    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tabs1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class TabsPageRoutingModule { }
```

**tabs2.routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuard } from 'src/app/gaurds/auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'tabs2',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: 'items',
                canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        loadChildren: () =>
                            import('../tabs2/items/items.module').then(m => m.ItemsgroupPageModule)
                    }

                ]
            },
            {
                path: 'subitems/:id',
                canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        loadChildren: () =>
                            import('../tabs2/subitems/subitems.module').then(m => m.SubitemsPageModule)
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                path: 'subtabs',
                canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                loadChildren: './subtabs/subtabs.module#SubtabsPageModule'
            },
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '/shared/tabs/tabs2/items',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            }
        ]

    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/shared/tabs/tabs2/items',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
  {  },
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class Tabs2RoutingModule { }
```

**subtabs.routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { SubtabsPage } from './Subtabs.page';
import { AuthGuard } from 'src/app/gaurds/auth.guard';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        component: SubtabsPageModule,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'subtabs-1/:subitems-id',
                canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        loadChildren: () =>
                            import('./subtabs-1/subtabs-1.module').then(m => m.Subtabs-1PageModule)

                    }

                ]
            },
            {
                path: 'subtabs-2/:subitems-id',
                canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        loadChildren: () =>
                            import('./subtabs-2/subtabs-2.module').then(m => m.Subtabs-2PageModule)

                    }

                ]
            },
            {
                path: 'subtabs-3/:subitems-id',
                canActivate: [AuthGuard],
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        loadChildren: () =>
                            import('./subtabs-3/subtabs-3.module').then(m => m.Subtabs-3PageModule)

                    }

                ]
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '/tabs/tabs2/subtabs/subtabs-1',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            }
        ]

    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tabs2/subtabs/subtabs-1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ScheduledetailsPageRoutingModule {
}
```

**Problem**

1. I am not able send the id's to all the subtabs/subitems as it requires id for showing data
2. Had put the id through subtabs, as follow:

   Introductions

   ```
       <ion-tab-button tab="subtabs-2/{{this.id}}">
           <ion-icon name="paper"></ion-icon>
           <ion-label>Legislations</ion-label>
       </ion-tab-button>

       <ion-tab-button tab="subtabs-3/{{this.id}}">
           <ion-icon name="apps"></ion-icon>
           <ion-label>Tasks</ion-label>
       </ion-tab-button>
   </ion-tab-bar>
   ```
3. The above will route to the first subtabs correctly, and fails in working of secondary tabs

Is there a better way to do this, or to changing the routing to nested tabs with params as the Data is constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't be the best method to follow.

After lot of searching, I added routerlink to the ion-tab tags

The routing works with taking the id from the routerlink,

```
<ion-tabs>
        <ion-tab-bar slot="top">
            <ion-tab-button tab="subtabs-1">
                <ion-icon name="book"></ion-icon>
                <ion-label>SubTabs 1</ion-label>
            </ion-tab-button>

            <ion-tab-button tab="subtabs-2" [routerLink]="['subtabs-2', this.id]">
                <ion-icon name="paper"></ion-icon>
                <ion-label>SubTabs 1</ion-label>
            </ion-tab-button>

            <ion-tab-button tab="subtabs-3" [routerLink]="['subtabs-3', this.id]">
                <ion-icon name="apps"></ion-icon>
                <ion-label>SubTabs 1</ion-label>
            </ion-tab-button>
        </ion-tab-bar>
    </ion-tabs>
```

> The Id will be provided by subtabs.page.ts
>   by declaring a variable as `id: any`.
>
> The value for id is being provided from subitems.page.ts.
>
> Here the id is subitems-id